# typeahead returns only the first 5 rows of the database

Tags: javascript, json, laravel-4, typeahead.js

Can anyone help me about this?
I have a form

```
 <form action={{'/query'}}  method="get" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" name="places" id="places">
        <input type="submit" value="Go">
 </form>
```

this is my search.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var places = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer:Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
    queryTokenizer:Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: '/query'
    
});

places.initialize();

$('#places').typeahead({
    hint:true,
    highLight: true,
    minLength:2
},{
    name:'places',
    displayKey: 'name',

    source: places.ttAdapter()

});
```

this is my route

```
Route::get('/query',['uses'=>HomeController@query]);
```

this is query function in HomeController

```
public function query()
{
    
    $query = Input::get('places');
    $results = DB::table('evac_center')->where('name','LIKE',$query.'%')->get();
    
    return Response::json($results);
}
```

this is the result
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3L2z.png)

The problem is whatever I type in the input box, the typeahead will only return the first 5 rows from my database.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `limit` in your dataset options:

```
$('#places').typeahead({
    hint:true,
    highLight: true,
    minLength:2
  },{
    name:'places',
    displayKey: 'name',
    limit: 25,
    source: places.ttAdapter()
  });
```

You may also have to set `sufficient` in your Bloodhound options:

```
var places = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer:Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
    queryTokenizer:Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: '/query',
    sufficient: 25
});
```

https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md
https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md